# Whole word search replace in SQL (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

I've a string containing control block references in ORACLE FORMS like below:-

```
SELECT NAME,DESIGNATION,POSTING
FROM SCOTT.EMP
WHERE NAME LIKE :PARAM.COL1
AND DESIGNATION LIKE :PARAM.COL12
AND POSTING LIKE :GLOBAL.POSTING
```

My requirement is to traverse above string, look for colons and then using NAME_IN & REPLACE functions to get actual values.

Problem is that replacing :PARAM.COL1 replaces both instances i.e. :PARAM.COL1 & :PARAM.COL12.

Can anybody suggest how can I replace :PARAM.COL1 & :PARAM.COL12 correctly.

Comment: You could replace longer strings first, or use regex_replace. But why are you replacing bind variables with fixed values?

Comment: Does this help http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/09/11/find-specific-or-similar-words-in-a-string-using-regular-expression-in-oracle/

Comment: @AlexPoole : Actually, I am creating a Form to run my Oracle Reports in 11g. Parameters with queries against each report are defined in a table. Using DBMS_SQL package queries are first validated. If I don't replace bind variables (referring to block columns) with actual values then DBMS_SQL will generate error.

Comment: And form is running fine as I've hard coded replace statements within a loop to replace :COL12 before :COL1 and so on.

Comment: But I wanted to use word match replace but couldn't find any function in SQL to do this task.

Comment: I don't understand - surely you should be [binding a value before you execute](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_sql.htm#ARPLS058), rather than replacing the placeholder?

Comment: @AlexPoole Thanks for identifying my problem. When I use dbms_sql.bind_variable it results into error "ORA-01003 - No statement parsed".

Comment: Then you haven't parsed it? I'm not sure if you are only using DBMS_SQL to verify the query and then trying to execute it a different way, or doing the whole thing through DBMS_SQL. I don't use Reports so I don't know what's possible or practical, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'try to figure out problem in my procedure and will let you know.

Comment: @AlexPoole You are right. There is no need to replace bind variables to hard coded values. My mistake was to use DBMS_SQL.BIND_VARIABLE before parse which was generating error each time.